# When df shows 40gb occupied out of total 50 and du shows 49.9gb occupied out of 50, can I store another 1-2 gb data or not?

Tags: disk-usage

I've read some 22 answers on similar questions on stack alone as to why df and du show diff results. But my concern is which one should I rely on? Which is practically reporting correctly?

I've only one boot disc on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTs, not any other/xtra external mounted discs, yet on my GCP Ubuntu server, df shows approx 40gb disk used out of 50 gb, while du and df both show 49.9gb used out of 50g.
[image: df and du show diff results]
Which one is true? I'm having hard time maintaining my server. Is it because my disk is almost 100% full or its because 4gb ram and 2 shared cores are not enough for my system.

[image: Ncdu result on same Gcp instance/server]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

You're including all mounted filesystems including RAM and pseudo filesystems in the `du` calculation whereas df is the actual one filesystem. Try adding `-x` to the du command.

Even then it may not be 100% accurate. There are so many different factors. Filesystem type, filesystem block size, physical block size, hard links, ref links, metadata, sparse files, etc, etc, etc. It's usually not an exact calculation in any case.

Comment: Thanks, for telling '-x' switch. But I've already read about the other so many complexities regarding file size calculations in Unix systems. But I'm still not clear, and wish to know, in the above scene, do I have 'some/1 or 2gb' free space to use or not? In other words, which is more accurate command for practical usage- df or du?

Comment: @BathindaHelper According to `df` you have *approximately* 9G free. So that. Certainly enough for 1 or 2G. The `du` calculation without `-x` is probably way higher than the real value.

Answer (score 0):

As written in their manpages, `du` calculates **file** space usage, while `df` calculates **filesystem** disk space usage.  Therefore `df` is a better tool for your use case.

You pass to `df` a partition (or a directory) as an argument to discover how much free space is left on that partition (or on the filesystems that hosts the partition). In your case, this is the result you are looking for, and you have about 9 Gb of free space left, as @CR. said in a comment.

On the other hand, `du` takes a file or directory as argument; if the directory contains subdirs from different filesystems, you'll get a disk usage count which is not meaningful. (In your output, observe how `du` is trying to navigate `/proc`, which is a pseudo filesystem which doesn't take any space.)
In this case, you have to remember to use the `-x` aka `--one-file-system` option, which skips directories on different filesystems.